# NSError to OSStatus

Tags: objective-c, macos, nserror

Is it possible to make OSStatus variable from NSError?
For example I get NSError with code 513(OSStatus equivalent = -5000) , but to process it in my App i need convert NSError(513) to OSStatus(-5000).

Answer (score 1):

NSError codes are domain-specific, you can easily create an NSError with your own @"Kira" domain and a custom status code 1337, and it would not map to any OSStatus.

The equivalence between certain NSError codes and OSStatus values is purely coincidental, and you should not rely on the actual numerical values of OSStatus anyway, you should use the defined constants/enums instead.